# Why does VS not define the alternative tokens for logical operators?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Alternative tokens are [**valid**](http://ideone.com/E0Jh8S) c++ [keywords](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword), yet in Visual Studio 2013 the following emits a compilation error (undeclared identifier):

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    int k(1), l(2);
    if (k and l) cout << "both non zero\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Since `and or not` have been around for quite some time, **is there a reason for not implementing them**?

Comment: What is the error message _exactly_?

Comment: I'm wondering **why** is that. It can't be implementation complexity and if they're afraid to break old code the same should apply for gcc et al. A simple grep/replace would resolve any of their codebase conflicts, so is there a deeper reason, is there a dispute behind the scenes or just a feature that nobody cared enough to ask?

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou A simple grep/replace would probably mess up a lot of comments.

Comment: GCC is generally *much* more cavalier about breaking old code in the name of standards conformance than MSVC is.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You ask about the rationale.  Here's one possible reason, not necessarily the one that most influenced the Visual C++ team:

1. Those are valid identifiers in C.
2. Microsoft's recommendation has long been to use C++ mode for both C and C++ code, rather than maintaining a modern C compiler.
3. Valid C code using these as identifiers would gratuitously break if they were compiled as keywords.
4. People trying to write portable C++ are mostly using `/permissive-` or `/Za` for maximum conformance anyway, which will cause these to be treated as keywords.
5. The workaround to treat them as keywords in `/Ze` by including a header file is easy and portable. (G++'s workaround `-fno-operator-names` isn't bad either, but putting the option in the source code rather than the build system is somewhat nicer.)

Comment: Could you amend the `/Za` part, please? Apparently it’s very buggy and Microsoft discourages its use (though not in the documentation of course, grrr). See https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/76pmky/til_c_has_and_or_and_not/dogao5m/

Comment: Also as a note, ``/Za`` causes a bug in MSVC which triggers compiler errors when including ``windows.h``. I made a report about this since I encountered this issue after checking this post: https://github.com/SasLuca/MSVCBug/blob/master/README.md

Comment: If you encounter problems with ``/Za`` just use ``/permissive-`` instead.

Answer (score 18):

VS is nonconforming. This is old news.

To use alternative tokens, include the `<ciso646>` header. According to the standard, including this header is supposed to have no effect in C++. However, you do need it in VS. So it's safe to just include it always, whenever there is any chance that you might be compiling with VS.

Comment: As it has been already noted, this "non-conformity" is only specific to the default compilation settings. Most (if not all) compilers are no-conforming in default mode. Specifying the `/Za` option removes this non-conformity from VS compiler.

Comment: gcc with C++11 or later without the -pthreads option is another good example.

Answer (score 15):

Modern Visual Studio (or rather, MSVC) *does* support alternative tokens; however, it does so only in [standards conformance mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=vs-2019). This mode comes with lots of goodies, so it should *always* be used.

To enable it, pass `/permissive-` to the compiler.

---

**The answer below is obsolete. This is now supported, see above!**

Previously, [Microsoft’s position was](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/312168/still-no-support-for-keywords-like-and-in-vc)<sup>1</sup> that

> `#include` of `<iso646.h>` (or `ciso646`) is how we support these keywords

And because “nobody” (before me, in 2007) ever requested this.

<sup>1</sup> link currently defunct; left here for archival purpose.

Answer (score 14):

Formally, these keywords *are* implemented and are supported intrinsically by the compiler without including any headers. However, for that you have to compile your source code in "more standard" mode of that C++ compiler, which means using the `/Za` option.

By intent, the `/Za` option is supposed to "disable compiler extensions". Of course, not supporting something that is supposed to be there in a compliant compiler cannot be formally qualified as a "compiler extension". Yet, that just the way things currently are.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, which is "why?"

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Well, it thought the "why" part came from "why not implemented?". Such question is based on an incorrect premise, since they actually *are* implemented.

Comment: The "extension" is to let the programmer have these names as identifiers.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Yes, but the formal definition of an "extension" clearly says that extensions are not allowed to break any compliant code. In other words, true extensions are allowed to "define what's undefined by the standard", but they are not allowed to "undefine (or redefine) what's already defined by the standard". Formally, extensions are allowed to *extend* the domain of compilable code, but not allowed to *shrink* it.

Comment: Sadly this is not actually an option for me because it results in lots of errors in standard headers such as `winnt.h(12723): error C2467: illegal declaration of anonymous 'struct'`.

Answer (score 3):

(contemporary update)

I made a small test: A New "Windows Desktop Application" Project. The IDE (Visual Studio 2017 15.7.5) sets, by default, the following C++ language conformance settings: ***/permissive- /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline***. In addition, I set the ***C++ Language Standard*** to ***ISO C++ /Latest draft*** (currently up to C++17). In addition, I added, in the main(), the following 2 lines:

```
bool a, b, c;

a = b and c;
```

It compiles the text-forms of the logical operators successfully. But when I altered the IDE ***Conformance mode*** to ***No*** (=> without ***/permissive-***) and re-compile, the compiler marks: "error C2065: 'and': undeclared identifier".

By default, the ***/permissive-*** compiler option is set in new projects created by Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5 (December 2017) and later versions. It is not set by default in earlier versions. So if someone created a project prior to version 15.5 and by the time update the IDE to the latest version, still it required to set in the project this compiler option manually.

The ***/Ze*** compiler option, which is on by default, enables Microsoft extensions. The ***/Ze*** option is deprecated because its behavior is on by default. MSDN recommends to use the ***/Zc*** (Conformance) compiler options to control specific language extension features.