# Error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'and'

Tags: c++, opencv, tesseract

I'm currently coding an app that will use OCR to read page numbers. I am using Visual Studio 2013 on a PC. I'm using C++ with OpenCV and Tesseract to complete this.

An error keeps on coming up and while I have come across similar problems,  I can't find anything where it specific relates to the identifier 'and'. As such, I don't know how to fix this problem. Here is the section of code that it applies to:

```
vector<string> PgNrOCR::runRecognition(const vector<Mat> &pgnrImage, int                   pgnrType)
{
    vector<string> output;

    output.resize(pgnrImage.size());

    for (size_t i = 0; i < pgnrImage.size(); i++)
    {
        if (!pgnrImage[i].empty() and pgnrType == 1)
            output[i] = runPrediction1(pgnrImage[i], i);
        if (!pgnrImage[i].empty() and pgnrType == 2)
            output[i] = runPrediction2(pgnrImage[i], i);
    }
    return (output);
}
```

The 'and' identifiers in the if statement are bringing up the error, so I need to find an alternative solution. The full error appears as so.

> Error  3   error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'and' c:\users\andrew\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\project1\project1\pgnrocr.cpp 152 1   PgTurn

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Does `and` have higher precedence than `!` or `==` ?

Comment: I have a feeling MSVC incorrectly requires you to `#include <ciso646>` to use these alternative tokens.

Comment: Adding #include <ciso646> did the trick, thank you @chris!

Comment: That dupe knows more than I do. You can use /Za to enable these (along with disabling other language extensions).

Answer (score 0):

can you try `&&` instead of `and`?

Comment: `&&` and `and` are lexically equivalent in conforming C++.

Comment: ok nvm, check this on how to enable alternative operators http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative

Comment: @chris oh first time to know that, do you know if this was always the case with all versions of C++?

Comment: To my knowledge, it has been like this since the beginning (at least the first standard). C has required the inclusion of a header.

Comment: might still be the reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414124/why-does-vs-not-define-the-alternative-tokens-for-logical-operators