# Cross-platform code label macro?

Tags: c++, region, pragma, preprocessor-directive

In MSVC & C#, `#pragma region` can be used to label a code section.
Similarly, in GCC/Clang, `#pragma mark` can accomplish the same thing.

Is it possible to define a single macro such as `CODELABEL(label)` which will work for both compilers?

Basically, I'd like to avoid having to do the following:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#pragma region Variables
#else
#pragma mark Variables
#endif
bool MyBool;
int MyInt;

#ifdef _WIN32
#pragma region Methods
#else
#pragma mark Methods
#endif
void MyMethod();
void AnotherMethod();
```

... and instead, do something like this:

```
CODELABEL( Variables )
bool MyBool;
int MyInt;
CODELABEL( Functions )
void MyMethod();
void AnotherMethod();
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, in C++11, you can use `_Pragma`, since using `#pragma` in a macro definition is not allowed:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#define PRAGMA(x) __pragma(x) //it seems like _Pragma isn't supported in MSVC
#else
#define PRAGMA(x) _Pragma(#x)
#endif

#ifdef _WIN32
#define CODELABEL(label) PRAGMA(region label)
#else
#define CODELABEL(label) PRAGMA(mark label)
#endif
```

The dance with `PRAGMA` is to satisfy `_Pragma` requiring a string literal, where side-by-side concatenation of two string literals (e.g., `"mark" "section label"`) doesn't work.

Comment: This seems like it should work, but MSVC is giving me `error C2059: syntax error : 'string'` wherever `CODELABEL(MyLabel)` is used

Comment: @RectangleEquals, Without looking too far into it, I'm thinking `_Pragma` is unsupported (even with /Za, unlike [alternative tokens](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24414420/962089)), but it's had its own `__pragma`, so that works.

Comment: Yep, that change seems to have done the trick. Haven't tested in OSX yet, though.

Comment: @RectangleEquals, My initial tests were with Clang if you mean that.

Comment: Yeah, Clang. If you've tested with it and it worked, then I'd say this case is closed.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637392/c-preprocessor-expand-macro-in-a-warning), the following should work.

```
#define STR_HELPER(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR_HELPER(x)

#ifdef _WIN32
  #define LABEL region
#else
  #define LABEL mark
#endif
```

and then

```
#pragma STR(LABEL) Variables
bool MyBool;
int MyInt;
#pragma STR(LABEL) Functions
void MyMethod();
void AnotherMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as Windows and macOS are concerned, since Xcode 12 and Visual Studio 2019, you can easily use this syntax that works ok on both platforms:

```
#pragma region mark -
#pragma region mark Whathever Your Label
```

Xcode silently ignores the 'region' token while VS takes the 'mark' token as part of the label, which is a minor cosmetic issue, IMHO.