# using word "not" as a name of c++ class causes error on VS2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm migrating existing project to VS2019. Having very simple structure that successfully compiled in all previous versions:

```
template <class Marker>
struct not
{
    // ...
```

> error C2332: 'struct': missing tag name

**NOTE-1** I've checked by pre-compilatinion generation that `not` is not substituted with some macros, output of `*.i` file fully matches declaration above

**NOTE-2** of course if I rename `not`->`inv` then all everything is right

Comment: Check http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.key#2: _the alternative representation `not` is reserved and shall not be used otherwise_.

Comment: `not` is a keyword in C and C++ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative, it is strange that it worked before

Comment: @RoQuOTriX: indeed. The question should not be "Why does this give an error now?" but "Why did this not give an error before?".

Comment: @Dewfy
check this out for more info - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376448/the-written-versions-of-the-logical-operators

Comment: @walnut - please make it as an answer - since you the only one who get  a point "how to resolve". Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`not` is a keyword in standard C++ which can be used as alternative for the `!` token.

MSVC does not support the alternative operator tokens by default. Therefore they are available as identifiers and you don't get an error on your declaration.

But in compliance mode with the `/permissive-` compiler flag, these tokens are considered keywords with their standard meaning and so they are not available as identifiers.

I suggest not using `not` as identifier, even when not using compliance mode, because that makes your code non-standard and non-portable.

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance

and [Why does VS not define the alternative tokens for logical operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414124/why-does-vs-not-define-the-alternative-tokens-for-logical-operators)

Answer (score 5):

`not` is a keyword in C++, it cannot be used as class name.

See [list of keywords](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword) on cppreference.

Answer (score 5):

`not` is an alternative operator for `!`, i.e. a C++ keyword and, thus, it **cannot** be used in naming.

See the [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative).