# C++17 Check if all elements in vector start with substring using lambda no loop

Tags: c++, c++17, stdvector

i have vector

```
std::vector<std::string> v = {"--d","--e","--f"};
```

i don't want to go with the loop rout

```
for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it){
    ...
}
```

is there any more elegant way to check if all elements in the vector start with "-" ?
can use c++17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`std::all_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of):

```
#include <algorithm>

bool startWithDash = std::all_of(v.begin(), v.end(),
  [](std::string const & e) { return not e.empty() and e.at(0) == '-'; });
```

This will work in C++11 and newer.

Comment: thanks "not" will not be valid in older VS IDE's better use standart

Comment: @user63898 `not` is definitely standard, see [alternative operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative). If it doesn't work in old VS versions, it's because they are famously very buggy and don't follow the standard by default. E.g. see [Why does VS not define the alternative tokens for logical operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414124/why-does-vs-not-define-the-alternative-tokens-for-logical-operators) for more info about this particular issue.

Comment: Oh, btw, I like using `not`, `and`, etc. because it makes the code more readable in my opinion. It reads more like plain English.

Comment: c++ is not python , and there are compilers that not understand it

Comment: @user63898 Yes, and those compilers are not standard compliant. In the case of MSVC, you can make it understand by telling it it needs to be standard compliant (using the `/Za` flag). Please read the pages I linked, this is completely standard C++.

Answer (score 1):

Using C++17, you can use `std::string_view`:

```
auto is_option = std::all_of(cbegin(v), cend(v),
  [](std::string_view sv) { return sv.substr(0,1) == "-"; });
```

In C++20, there will even be [`string_view::starts_with`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/starts_with) and one could use `sv.starts_with("-")` inside the lambda.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
#include <algorithm>

bool allBeginWithMinus = std::all_of(v.begin(), v.end(), [v](std::string& str)->bool
return (!str.empty() && ("-" == str.front()))});
```

Comment: @user63898 The `-> bool` part is not strictly necessary if the return type can be automatically deduced, which is the case here.

Comment: i know, its better to set it good hint for the compiler